# Tweepy module says not installed

Tags: python, module, package, tweepy

I realize this question might come off as an easy fix, but it has been annoying me for the last hour. I'm new to working in a Python environment on my Mac, and I can't seem to install the tweepy module in the directory that I'm working in.

First I installed Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Next I installed Python:

```
brew install python
```

Which resulted in:

```
Python has been installed as /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Then I attempted to install the Tweepy package within the path /Desktop/twitterBot:

```
pip3 install tweepy --user
```

Which resulted in:

```
Successfully installed tweepy-3.9.0
```

After this I wanted to check that the Tweepy package was successfully installed, so within my bot.py file, the only line I wrote was `import tweepy`

When attempted to run my code `python bot.py` within the path Desktop/twitterBot, I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bot.py", line 1, in <module>
import tweepy
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

I really appreciate your guys' help. Thanks.

Comment: You installed tweepy with pip *3+ for python3. => You need to use the correct python compiler. Use ``python3 bot.py``

Answer (score 1):

[As explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382004/tweepy-module-says-not-installed#comment113856410_64382004), you're running your code with a different version of Python than the one you installed Tweepy for.

> Mac OS X 10.8 comes with Python 2.7 pre-installed by Apple.

> Remember that if you choose to install a newer Python version from python.org, you will have two different but functional Python installations on your computer, so it will be important that your paths and usages are consistent with what you want to do.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html

Since you installed Tweepy for Python 3 with `pip3`, you'll need to use `python3` to run your code.
See https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.